# JMeter as code assertions are not being considered in test results

Tags: java, maven, jmeter

I'm using JMeter as a code (programmatic approach instead of GUI, with a Java Maven project) in order to stress-test an AWS Lambda Serverless API.

I've already developed a test plan, thread group, HTTPSamplerProxy and so on...

The execution of the calls to the API works perfect but is not the case e.g. for the DurationAssertion I've added to the HTTP Sampler..

I've also set a CSV file for the output where after execution I see everything ok (status code 200..), but the test should fail due to it is over the DurationAssertion I've configured (in addition to other assertion test elements).

I thought that perhaps I had to set "enabled" = true in the DurationAssertion object, but no effect.. Also, I've tried to access the JMeter Context in this way:

```
JMeterContextService.getContext().getPreviousResult()
```

I expected above code to retrieve a SampleResult (which has an AssertionResult collection), but the SampleResult is null..

A test plan with test elements (DurationAssertion in this case) without its respective analysis of the results of these assertions make no sense.. I want to see a failure message in each call that exceeds a certain threshold.. If I'd be using the JMeter GUI, I would add a ViewResultTree, which shows a Sampler Result view with detail of the request, response, and associated test asserts. And in addition to assertion result (per each request) I wanna see the request payload, full response, headers.. But in programmatic mode (without using the GUI).

So I would highly appreciate if anyone could give me some hint in how to accomplish this goal but by code.

**UPDATE 1**: I share a github snippet with the entire source code, such as UBIK LOAD PACK user suggested me:

https://gist.github.com/svillarreal/5eb90a66b8972633b95c249abb3566da

**UPDATE 2**: [Inspection of context object (evaluated after JMeter engine finished run) - All null inside](https://screenshot.net/z50necx)

**UPDATE 3**

i) I've recently found a jmeter.properties file, where I've configured the following properties:

```
    jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=xml
    jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results=all
```

And now the output as XML instead of CSV shows, at least, the sent request payload and the response data, which is VERY useful for analyse error cases.

ii) I did the inspection of JMeterContextService.getContext() inside the JMeterEngine execution instead of after it finishes run and then I could realize that there is one context per thread group, and during its run this object is full so now is clear why in **UPDATE 2** all the properties are null..

Best regards and thanks!

Comment: can you share the full code using snippet in github or pastebin ?

Comment: Sure: https://gist.github.com/svillarreal/5eb90a66b8972633b95c249abb3566da TAL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could fix this. The issue was that I was managing erroneously the tree that is passed to the StandardJMeterEngine.

In JMeter everything is based on this tree, and like in the GUI, we should take care about how the elements are positioned in its hierarchy.

Analysing the library and debugging it intensely I've realized more in deep how JMeter works and I've understood that everything is managed starting from the HashTree. So the solution was to add the DurationAssertion and ResponseAssertion as HTTPSamplerProxy node's childs instead of putting them as HTTPSamplerProxy's test elements.

In particular, the method that fills the assertions to check after the execution is the following (and that let me know how to manage the hashtree):

```
    // org.apache.jmeter.threads.TestCompiler 

    private void saveSamplerConfigs(Sampler sam) {
        List<ConfigTestElement> configs = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Controller> controllers = new LinkedList<>();
        List<SampleListener> listeners = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Timer> timers = new LinkedList<>();
        List<Assertion> assertions = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<PostProcessor> posts = new LinkedList<>();
        LinkedList<PreProcessor> pres = new LinkedList<>();
        for (int i = stack.size(); i > 0; i--) {
            addDirectParentControllers(controllers, stack.get(i - 1));
            List<PreProcessor>  tempPre = new LinkedList<>();
            List<PostProcessor> tempPost = new LinkedList<>();
            List<Assertion> tempAssertions = new LinkedList<>();
            for (Object item : testTree.list(stack.subList(0, i))) {
                if (item instanceof ConfigTestElement) {
                    configs.add((ConfigTestElement) item);
                }
                if (item instanceof SampleListener) {
                    listeners.add((SampleListener) item);
                }
                if (item instanceof Timer) {
                    timers.add((Timer) item);
                }
                if (item instanceof Assertion) {
                    tempAssertions.add((Assertion) item);
                }
                if (item instanceof PostProcessor) {
                    tempPost.add((PostProcessor) item);
                }
                if (item instanceof PreProcessor) {
                    tempPre.add((PreProcessor) item);
                }
            }
            assertions.addAll(0, tempAssertions);
            pres.addAll(0, tempPre);
            posts.addAll(0, tempPost);
        }

        SamplePackage pack = new SamplePackage(configs, listeners, timers, assertions,
                posts, pres, controllers);
        pack.setSampler(sam);
        pack.setRunningVersion(true);
        samplerConfigMap.put(sam, pack);
    }
```

Also I had to activate the following property:

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.assertion_results_failure_message=true
```

As a consequence now I have my CSV file report with the assertions results messages included in a exclusive column for that.

Well, issue resolved. ** I've updated the github snippet gist with the final solution ** Many thanks to all that read this post and tried to collaborate.

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

I can think about at least one use case when your approach will not work: JMeter didn't receive response from the server at all.

For example if your server gets overloaded it might be the case that JMeter will never get response back therefore your Duration Assertion will simply not be applied as [PostProcessors, Listeners and Assertions are not fired](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder) given that SampleResult is null.

So in order to be on the safe side I would recommend applying [connect](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#setConnectTimeout-java.lang.String-) and [response](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerBase.html#setResponseTimeout-java.lang.String-) timeouts to your HTTP Request sampler(s)

```
HTTPSamplerProxy httpSampler = new HTTPSamplerProxy();
httpSampler.setConnectTimeout("3000");
httpSampler.setResponseTimeout("3000");
//etc.
```

If you have > 1 HTTP Request sampler in Test Plan it makes sense to go for [HTTP Request Defaults](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/why-its-so-important-use-jmeters-http-request-defaults) instead of setting the timeouts individually.

Comment: Before all thank for your response. I read your idea and although it improves the case (the connect and response timeouts work perfect), it is not enough to meet my needs due to I do depend of assertions test elements, perhaps those would not be very complex but the idea in future is being able to add another kind of assertions, e.g. a JDBC / Beanshell / Compare assertion. Regards,